# VBS script won't run macro and save

Tags: excel, vbscript

The following code has continued to fail at Line 15 (i.e., the macro isn't running). The named macro runs fine if I open Excel manually and run it, and I was able to get it to run previously but could not get the file to save. It seems to me that there's a somewhat obvious coding error I'm missing, but I'm having trouble debugging it.

EDIT: The error I'm gettiing is on the xlApp.Run line saying that the Server threw an exception.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   


xlApp.visible = True
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 

set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("N:\FILEPATHHIDDEN\SPREADSHEET.xlsm", 1, False)
xlApp.Run "RefreshPQ"
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close

xlApp.Quit()

xlBook = Nothing
xlApp = Nothing

'Leaves an onscreen message!
    MsgBox dataCalc & " vbs successfully completed!",         vbInformation 

'
```

Comment: where is the macro "RefreshPQ" located? In the current workbook? or in the "SPREADSHEET.xlsm"? You need to include the workbook name in the latter case.

Comment: It's in Module1 of the 'Spreadsheet.xlsm'. IIRC, this is the instance where I need to use "FILE!Module1.ModuleName". I'll give it a try.